# Why my cout is not showing string in output?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Team {
  public:
  string teamName ;
  string playerOne ;
  string PlayerTwo ;
  string playerThree ;
  double totalRunsScored;
};
void welcomeMessage();
void dispTeam(Team t1,Team t2);
void roleSelection(Team t1,Team t2);
int currentBatsmen;
int currentBowler;
int main()
{
    welcomeMessage();
    Team t1,t2 ;
    dispTeam(t1,t2);
    cout<<"\n lets start first innings \n";
    roleSelection(t1,t2);
    return 0;
}

void welcomeMessage(){
cout << "Welcome to gully Cricket \n";
cout<< "\n";
cout<< "\n";
cout<< "\n";
cout << "Enter the name of your team players for Team one and Two\n ";
}
void dispTeam(Team t1,Team t2) {

   getline(cin,t1.playerOne);
   getline(cin,t1.PlayerTwo);
   getline(cin,t1.playerThree);
   cout << "\n Team one \t" <<"\t" <<t1.playerOne << "\t" << t1.PlayerTwo << "\t" << t1.playerThree <<"\t" << endl ;

   getline(cin,t2.playerOne);
   getline(cin,t2.PlayerTwo);
   getline(cin,t2.playerThree);
   cout << "\n Team Second \t" << "\t" <<t2.playerOne <<"\t"<< t2.PlayerTwo <<"\t"<< t2.playerThree <<"\t" << endl ;
}
void roleSelection(Team a,Team b){
    cout<<"Choose Your batsmen from Team one press 1,2,3 : \n";
    cin >> currentBatsmen;
    if (currentBatsmen==1){
     cout<<a.playerOne;
    }else if (currentBatsmen==2){
    cout<<"you have chosen \t" << a.PlayerTwo <<" \t as your batsmen";
    }else if(currentBatsmen==3){
    cout<<"you have chosen \t "<< a.playerThree <<" \t as your batsmen";
    }
}
```

**in this function roleselection()** my cout is showing blank and i am not able to understand why? above you can see my code as suggested i have included string header file too and also iostream. It works well in dispTeam() function.

Comment: Define "showing blank". Is there no output at all? Is there output but the player strings are blank? Is the prompt output but the choice reports not, or vice-versa, or some combination? What inputs have you tested, and what are the results in each case?

Comment: `std::endl` sends a newline and a `std::flush` (which is what makes your text show up) . Either change to `endl` or add a `<< flush`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how you pass the arguments to your functions:

```
void dispTeam(Team t1,Team t2);
```

This means that the `Team` object are being passed by *value*, which means the local argument variables inside the function will be *copies* of the original object. The function will then continue to modify these copies, which are independent and distinct from the original objects.

You need to pass by *reference* to pass references to the original objects:

```
// Note ampersands here and here, meaning pass by reference
//                v        v
void dispTeam(Team& t1,Team& t2);
```

Comment: Thank you i did not realize that